# how to divide and multiply variables inside quote marks

Tags: bash

I am trying to get a result of percentage with the following;

```
for FNAME in *_1.fq
do
FILE=${FNAME##*/}
SAMPLE=${FILE%_1.fq}
echo "processing ${SAMPLE}"
let "Raw_reads = $((`cat ${SAMPLE}_1.fq | wc -l` / 4)) + $((`cat ${SAMPLE}_2.fq | wc -l` / 4))"
let "Error_corrected = $((`cat unfixrm_${SAMPLE}_1.cor.fq | wc -l` / 4)) + $((`cat unfixrm_${SAMPLE}_2.cor.fq | wc -l` / 4))"
let "Error_corrected_per = ($Error_corrected / $Raw_reads) * 100"
echo -e "$SAMPLE\t$Raw_reads\t$Error_corrected($Error_corrected_per%)"
done
```

I get this result; how do I get (44%) and (20%)

```
processing FB_0d
FB_0d   100     44(0%)
processing FB_2d
FB_2d   200     40(0%)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, i.e., `44/200` equals 0 in integer arithmetic, and multiplying 0 with anything also results in 0, I suggest the following alternatives:

Either do, in your formula, multiplication by 100 first, and division last, i.e.

```
((Error_corrected_per = (Error_corrected * 100) / Raw_reads))
```

Another possibility (if this is an option for you) would be to rewrite your program in, for instance, zsh instead of bash, where you have floating point arithmetic.